# Cakephp3 transaction find query

Tags: mysql, select, transactions, cakephp-3.0

When making a transaction in cakephp3 and adding a get() query inside all works fine. But why is a find() query not performed inside the transaction?

I have the following controller in cakephp3:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException;

use Cake\Network\Session;
use Cake\Event\Event;

use Cake\Network\Http\Client;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

class DashboardController extends AppController {
        public function index(){
            $conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');

            $testModel = TableRegistry::get('Tests');

            $select1=array();
            $select2 = array();
            $saved = array();
            $conn->transactional(function ($connection)use(&$testModel,&$select1,&$select2,&$saved) {
                $select1 = $testModel->find('all')->where(['id' => 2]); // article with id 12

                $select2 = $testModel->get(1);
                $select2->content = 'foo';
                $saved = $testModel->save($select2);
            });
        }

    }
 ?>
```

I would expect to get this in the SQL-Log:

```
BEGIN
SELECT Tests.id AS `Tests__id`, Tests.content AS `Tests__content` FROM tests Tests WHERE id = 2
SELECT Tests.id AS `Tests__id`, Tests.content AS `Tests__content` FROM tests Tests WHERE Tests.id = 1 LIMIT 1
UPDATE tests SET content = 'foo' WHERE id = 1
COMMIT
```

But instead I get:

```
BEGIN
SELECT Tests.id AS `Tests__id`, Tests.content AS `Tests__content` FROM tests Tests WHERE Tests.id = 1 LIMIT 1
UPDATE tests SET content = 'foo' WHERE id = 1
COMMIT
SELECT Tests.id AS `Tests__id`, Tests.content AS `Tests__content` FROM tests Tests WHERE id = 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's working fine for me, I would suspect that you have an additional query outside of the transactional callback, which also looks for `id = 2`, as the query being generated by your shown `find()` call will never be executed, since queries are being lazy evaluated.

For now you've just created a query object, and in order to actually execute it, you'll have to call `all()`, `first()`, `toArray()`, etc.., or iterate over it.

See also **[Cookbook > ...ORM > Query Builder > How Are Queries Lazily Evaluated](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#how-are-queries-lazily-evaluated)**

Comment: awesome, thanks! lazy loading was the keyword. the query gets executed after the transaction because I was accessing the results of the query there. thanks!